# Problems with navigating directories

Tags: php

I am trying to go one directory lower using this code in PHP:

```
define ('INC_ROOT',__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..');
```

When I echo the constant INC_ROOT, it gives me this...

> C:\wamp\www\guru\includes..

while I am actually expecting to get this:

> C:\wamp\www\guru\

Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Why do you expect that?You concatenate to the constant the separator  and ..   This is a string you are not navigating down one level with ..

Comment: so how then do i navigate one level down given the code above?

Comment: Try `define ('INC_ROOT',realpath(__DIR__ . '/..'));`

Comment: `$parent_dir = dirname(__DIR__);` will give you the parent directory.

Comment: They both work differently but im now getting what i needed. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use.

```
define ('INC_ROOT',realpath(dirname(__DIR__) . '/..'));
```

Comment: I get that, but i need to go one directory lower than this path

Answer (score 0):

You can define the variable in a new file of location `C:\wamp\www\guru\` and include the file in other necessary files with relative path.